# How to output file & ignoring lines that start with "?"?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, subversion

I do `svn status --show-updates` and then I want to either

- Q1:
  ignore (not to display) lines that start with `?`
- Q2: 
  display only lines that start with `*` Note that there are few spaces before * occurs. That means that `*` is not the first character on the line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can express those conditions using regular expressions and use `grep` to filter the results based on those.

The first one is `^?`. The carat is a special character that represents the beginning of a line; so that expression matches the beginning of the line immediately followed by a `?`.

The second one is `^ *\*`. The `*` is a special character that qualifies the preceding character - it means the preceding character may appear zero or more times. Since `*` is a special character, the one you're looking for needs to be escaped, hence, `\*`. So that expression will match the beginning of a line followed by zero or more spaces, followed by an asterisk.

For your first condition, use the `-v` option for `grep` to negate the results.

So finally,

```
svn status --show-updates | grep -v '^?'
```

or

```
svn status --show-updates | grep '^ *\*'
```

Regular expressions are very powerful, so many Unix tools can use them. They are very much worth learning. There is a great tutorial at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Depending on which grep, the `?` may have special meaning.  If so, you need to escape it `\?`

Answer (score 1):

Q1: A simple way is the following

```
svn st --show-updates -q
```

st is the abbreviation for status, and -q for quiet : that will exclude files that aren't already added in the repository.

Q2: if you didn't named your files with a *, you can also do this:

```
svn status --show_updates|grep -v \*
```